# White spots and dried tips on key lime trees

Tags: diseases, fruit-trees, pests, citrus

We grew two key lime trees from seeds. They are now about 3 years old. A few weeks ago they started developing white spots on some of the leaves and some of the new shoots died off. We live in Southern California and keep them in pots outside year round and they've been growing fine so far.
Any suggestions what could be wrong/what to do about it would be much welcomed.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]